# How to get the "serizable" list of permissions from a mention

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a command that can show you the full list of permissions in the serialized form of the person you mention. It's like this line: `console.log(message.member.permissions.serialize(true));`
Instead of getting the message sender's permissions with `message.member`, I want to get the `.permissions.serialize(true)` of the person that they mention. I tried `args.permissions.serialize(true)` but that doesnt work.

How do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to interact with the mentioned member's guildMember object, you'll want to go into the message's mentions' first member.

`let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.cache.first();`

From here, you can do whatever you wanted to do with the `mentionedMember` object.
(It returns a GuildMember object) To do what you wanted, have a look below.

```js
let mentionedMember = message.mentions.members.cache.first();
let memberPermsList = mentionedMember.permsissions.serialize(true);
```

That's it! What I basically did there is get the GuildMember object of the first mentioned member and get the permissions list of the object returned.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to get the first member mentioned in the message.

```js
const taggedMember = message.mentions.members.first();
```

Then, you should be able to get the serialized permissions:

```js
const permissions = taggedMember.permissions.serialize();
```

See: [Message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message), [MessageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions), [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

Comment: It's that easy? I do an entire toArray-map-format-replace cycle to get a list of perms